# Lattice-isotopic essentialization of arrangements

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, linear-algebra, discrete-geometry

I'm working on a problem related to 
$\textbf{Randell's isotopy theorem}$ for complex hyperplane arrangements. I have a question which seems quite obvious. However, I haven't found a rigorous proof yet. I'm pretty sure this is a well known fact in hyperplane arrangements theory. All rigorous definitions and notations are available in [Randell's original paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1989-107-02/S0002-9939-1989-0984812-7/S0002-9939-1989-0984812-7.pdf) and in [this expository notes](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/sp06stanley.pdf) by Stanley.

$\textbf{Question}$ 
Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ two complex hyperplanes arrangements in $\mathbb{C}^{d}.$ If the essentializations $\operatorname{ess}(\mathcal{A})$ and 
$\operatorname{ess}(\mathcal{B})$ are lattice-isotopic, then the arrangements 
$\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are lattice-isotopic.

Comment: Does the obvious proof (explicitly construct the isotopy) not work?

Comment: You are right. I only had some problems in writing down the explicit construction of the lattice isotopy from the one at the level of essential arrangements. Fortunately, I was able to solve.